# How to root lg optimus logic

Tags: rooting, lg-optimus-logic

For the past few days I have been googling the different ways to root my LG Optimus Logic, and have come up short handed. There doesn't seem to be a help forum for this phone anywhere, or at least not one that I've found.

Does anybody have this phone or know what rooting method will work? I have tried several already with no luck.

Comment: I have linked your question to our [Rooting Guides Index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). You might check there for related devices or common rooting methods, maybe you find something working there already. If so, don't hesitate to answer your own question (and later accept your answer) to help others as well :)

Comment: This phone closely resembles LG Optimus L3. It might be just a rebrand. As such try following this [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1863117)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I Tries SuperOneClick and it worked for my lg l35g AKA lg optimus logic (net 10).